# How can I call the constructor of the grand parent class?

Tags: java, inheritance

How can we call the constructor of grand parent.

eg: `B` inherits from `A` and `C` inherits from `B`.

I need to call the constructor of `A` in `C`. Is it possible without creating an instance of `B`?

If i need this how this can be implemented in Java.

Comment: Can you give more detail as to why you need to call the grand parent's constructor w/o calling the parent's? Off-the-cuff, if class C needs to call the constructor of class A without calling the constructor of class B, it sounds like you may need to look at your design instead of trying to figure out a way to skip calling the parent's constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `super()` from C and from B to access A's constructor

```
class A {
    public A() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public B() {
        super();
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

class C extends B {
    public C() {
        super();
        System.out.println("C");
    }
}

public class Inheritance {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C();
    }
}
```

Output :

> A
>   B
>   C

**Note:**

If all are default constructor then *no need* to write `super();` it will implicitly call it.

If there is parametrized constructor then `super(parameter.. )` is needed

Comment: one more question ..the same behavior will happen in case of c++

Comment: @Ashish Check it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120876/c-superclass-constructor-calling-rules)

Answer (score 6):

You can't invoke the constructor of `A` directly in the constructor of `C`.

You can (and actually must) call it indirectly, 'though. Each constructor of `B` has to call a constructor of `A` (either explicitly or implicitly). Since every constructor of `C` needs to call one of the constructors of `B` you will **always** call one of `A`s constructors.

Answer (score 2):

C will have to call B's constructor and in turn B will call A's constructor...
there is No other option to call **Grand parent's constructor**

Answer (score 0):

An example to Joachim's answer:

```
class A {
    A() { System.out.print("A()")};
    A(Object o) { System.out.print("A(Object)")};
}
class B {
    B() { super(); System.out.print("B()")};
    B(Object o) { super(o); System.out.print("B(Object)")};
}
class C {
    C() { super(); System.out.print("C()")};
    C(Object o) { super(o); System.out.print("C(Object)")};
}
```

Now calling:

```
C c = new C();
```

will produce: `A()B()C()`, while calling:

```
C c = new C(new Object());
```

will produce: `A(Object)B(Object)C(Object)`.

As you can see, by manipulating `super()` call you can actually call explicit parent constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you have class B extending class A, you can't avoid to call the constructor method for A when you create an instance of the class B. If this mechanism doesn't seems clear to you, I recommend this reading about Java's inheritance system: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html .

Here's an example:

```
class A {
    public A() {
        doSomethingA();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public B() {
        super(); // this is the call to the A constructor method
        doSomethingB();
    }
}

class C extends B {
    public C() {
        super(); // this is the call to the B constructor method
        doSomethingC();
    }
}
```

Creating a new object with `new C()` will involve, in order, the calling of `A() - B() - C()`