# Manually calling constructor of base class outside initialization list

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a `Derived` class whose constructor has to populate the fields of a `struct` that is passed as an argument to the constructor of the `Base` class. I want to be able to name the fields of the struct that I am populating, to keep my code future-proof (i.e.: resistant to addition and/or reordering of the members of `MyStruct`).

Note that `struct MyStruct` has default values, so it cannot be initialised with named fields directly in the initialization list (e.g.: `Base({.a = a, .b = b})` does not work). Also, in my case, `Base`'s copy constructor is deleted. Also, I am using C++ 11.

The solution I came up with uses the `placement new` operator to manually call the constructor of the `Base` class on the memory pointed to by `this`. To achieve this I also had to add a `protected` default constructor to my `Base` class. Are there any possible downsides to this approach and/or could anyone suggest a better method?

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyStruct
{
        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;
};

class Base
{
public:
        Base(MyStruct str){
                std::cout << "a: " << str.a << ", b: " << str.b << "\n";
        }
        Base(Base&&) = delete; // no copy constructor
protected:
        Base(){ // dummy, does exactly nothing.
                // it only exists to be called by
                // the derived class's constructor
        }
private:
        int amember;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
        Derived(int a, int b)
        {
                MyStruct str;
                str.a = a;
                str.b = b;
                new (this) Base(str);
        }
private:
        int anothermember;
};

int main()
{
        MyStruct str;
        str.a = 10;
        str.b = 20;
        Base b(str);
        Derived d(10, 20);
        return 0;
}
```

edit: added mention that Base cannot be copied, made explicit that `Base::Base()` does exactly nothing.

Comment: Are you looking for [named-arguments](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/12/14/named-arguments-cpp/)?

Comment: I was looking at that before I came up with this solution of using the struct instead. I think named arguments is a feature that C++ really needs, and the solution provided there is more complicated than I'd like it to be.

Comment: The second paragraph does not seem to make sense. Designated initializers will be added in C++20 and `Base({.a = a, .b = b})` will be correct.  Some compilers already support.

Comment: yup c++20 will hopefully bring that, but the question is tagged c++11. Is it the mention that "`Base` cannot be copied" that you think doesn't make sense? I will rephrase that. I mean that in this case, the `Base` class has a deleted copy constructor, which I had to clarify after @NathanOliver's original answer (now edited) was assuming the copy constructor was available. I will clarify again now.

Comment: Base's copy constructor has nothing to do with this

Comment: Do you mean strictly C++11 ? (usually people mean "c++11 or later" when using that tag unless otherwise clarified)

Comment: I clarified that C++11 is what I am on, thanks. Regarding Base's copy constructor, the clarification was needed because @NathanOliver's original answer was making use of the copy constructor, so I had to clarify it. They have since amended it, but I left the clarification there, just to avoid future answers to rely on it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a helper function instead like

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
        Derived(int a, int b) : Base(make_mystruct(a, b)), anothermember(some_value) {}
private:
        int anothermember;
        static MyStruct make_mystruct(int a, int b) { return MyStruct(a, b); }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned that `Base` doesn't have a copy constructor. I will update the question.

Comment: Of course! Thanks a lot, that looks neat. Could you point out any disadvantages of my approach versus yours?

Comment: @oromoiluig one I don't know if your code is legal or not but I know this code is legal, so that's a plus for me.  Also, if your `Base` class has a destructor that has observable side effects, then by not calling the destructor before using placement new you will also have undefined behavior.

Comment: Good point about the destructor. Given how the protected default constructor of Base() does exactly nothing, that wouldn't be a problem, but it's definitely not neat.

Comment: or just `Base({a,b})`

Comment: @M.M, your solution wouldn't fulfill my requirement  "I want to be able to name the fields of the struct that I am populating, to keep my code future-proof (i.e.: resistant to addition and/or reordering of the members of MyStruct)."

Comment: @oromoiluig there is no possible solution to those requirements , you have to rely on argument order at some stage. (until designated initializers are added in C++20 that is)

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to add that this could be a good opportunity to use **IILE**, Immediately Invoked Lambda Expression, if you for whatever reason don't want a named helper function:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
Derived(int a, int b) : Base{[](){
    MyStruct str;
    str.a = a;
    str.b = b;
    return str; }()}
    {}
};
```

The benefit is that you will not need to construct the class and it's members *only once*, since you do everything in the initialization list. If you in the future add non-trivial members to Base, you will be will not have to pay for double initialization.