# Is there a way to add a QWidget to a QMenu in QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qmenu

I'm creating a text editor and I'd like to put the `QComboBox` in the `QMenu`. I didn't find any method inside the `QMenu` that handled such a thing. The closest is `QMenu::addAction()`. I was wondering of getting around this hurdle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to subclass [`QWidgetAction`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidgetaction.html) and then simply call the [`addAction`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmenu.html#addAction-5) to your menu.

Example code for Spin Box Action with a label

```
class SpinBoxAction : public QWidgetAction {
public:
    SpinBoxAction (const QString& title) : 
      QWidgetAction (NULL) {
        QWidget* pWidget = new QWidget (NULL);
        QHBoxLayout* pLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
        QLabel* pLabel = new QLabel (title);  //bug fixed here, pointer was missing
        pLayout->addWidget (pLabel);
        pSpinBox = new QSpinBox(NULL);
        pLayout->addWidget (pSpinBox);
        pWidget->setLayout (pLayout);

        setDefaultWidget(pWidget);
    }

    QSpinBox * spinBox () {
        return pSpinBox;
    }

private:
    QSpinBox * pSpinBox;
};
```

Now simply create it and add it to your menu

```
SpinBoxAction * spinBoxAction = new SpinBoxAction(tr("Action Title"));
// make a connection
connect(spinBoxAction ->spinBox(), SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), 
        this, SLOT(spinboxValueChanged(int)));
// add it to your menu
menu->addAction(spinBoxAction);
```

Comment: Why would you prefer subclassing QWidgetAction? Wouldn't it offer looser coupling and more maintainable code to instantiate a QWidgetAction separately from your `pWidget` and call `setDefaultWidget`? Wouldn't the only reason to subclass be to implement `createWidget`?

Comment: It depends. If you want to have reusable widget actions and avoid rewriting the same parts of code for creating them you should subclass them. For example I once needed a QMenu with multiple spin boxes with a label, and varying min/max values and prefix. By subclassing the `QWidgetAction` I was able to have a reusable element, and in every case I only had to change the constructor arguments. Also it is straight forward to create a small library with action widgets and just call the one you need when you need it.

Comment: I'm not familar with this kind of constructor:`SpinBoxAction (const QString& title) : 
      QWidgetAction (NULL) {}`

Comment: This simply calls the parent's constructor with `NULL` as argument. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120876/c-superclass-constructor-calling-rules

Comment: @MagnusHoff So why would you need to implement createWidget?

Answer (score 2):

[`QWidgetAction`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidgetaction.html) is a `QAction` that contains a `QWidget`. You can use this to encapsulate your `QComboBox` and add it to your menu via `QMenu::addAction`.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a `QWidget` or `QFrame` as the Menu Widget, then put a `QHBoxLayout` on it, and insert your `QWidgets` inside.

Comment: This idea actually occured to me. I'm kinda new to Qt so forgive me if this is kinda basic: How would I set my own QWidget as the Menu Widget.