# Why QMenu's separator doesn't show text?

Tags: qt, qmenu, qaction

My goal is to make menu with labeled separators.
So, I am running this code:

```
QMenu *menu = new QMenu;

QAction *group1 = menu->addSeparator();
group1->setText("Group of actions #1");
menu->addAction("Action #1");
menu->addAction("Action #2");
menu->addAction("Action #3");

QAction *group2 = menu->addSeparator();
group2->setText("Group of actions #2");
menu->addAction("Action #1");
menu->addAction("Action #2");
menu->addAction("Action #3");

QToolButton btn;
btn.setText("Click me");
btn.setMenu(menu);
btn.setPopupMode(QToolButton::InstantPopup);

btn.show();
```

and got this

[image: QMenu's separator text not shown]

instead of this (I created it by MS Paint :) )

[image]

What's wrong?

**EDIT:** Yes, there are another question like this ([Non interactive items in QMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635903/non-interactive-items-in-qmenu)), but maybe more simplier way exists?

**One of solutions** is using "Fusion" theme :) I just added code below into `int main` function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication::setStyle("Fusion");
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    ...
```

Comment: Saw that question, but I thought there are more simplier solution. And more native

Comment: If you can use Qt 5.1, it looks like `addSection(const QString &)` might work.

Comment: Yes, it's most correct way :) But `addSection` displays only line too.  read comments just now [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635903/non-interactive-items-in-qmenu#comment41418855_22647236). The problem is OS-specific (Win 7). Well, thank you for help! What to do with question now?

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that. It seems the best bet might be a custom widget if it needs to work in Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need a text styled separator for my Qt menu. How can I do that?

I resolve the problem like that:

```
QWidgetAction* MyWidget::createTextSeparator(const QString& text)
{
    auto* pLabel = new QLabel(text);
    pLabel->setMinimumWidth(this->minimumWidth() - 4);
    // grayish style
    pLabel->setStyleSheet("background: #FF4B4B4B;");
    // possible alignment
    // pLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    auto* separator = new QWidgetAction(this);
    separator->setDefaultWidget(pLabel);
    return separator;
}

pMenu->addAction(createTextSeparator("Group of actions"));
```

Comment: This answer belongs to the [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635903/non-interactive-items-in-qmenu).