# Calling the base class constructor from the derived class constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, visibility, derived-class

I have a question:

Say I have originally these classes which I can't change (let's say because they're taken from a library which I'm using):

```
class Animal_
{
public:
    Animal_();
    int getIdA()
    {
        return idA;
    };
    string getNameA()
    {
        return nameA;
    }
private:
    string nameA;
    int idA;
}

class Farm
{
public :
    Farm()
    {
        sizeF=0;
    }
    Animal_* getAnimal_(int i)
    {
        return animals_[i];
    }
    void addAnimal_(Animal_* newAnimal)
    {
        animals_[sizeF]=newAnimal;
        sizeF++;
    }
    
private:
    int sizeF;
    Animal_* animals_[max];
}
```

But then I needed a class where I just add couple of fields so I did this:

```
class PetStore : public Farm
{
public :
    PetStore()
    {
     idF=0;
    };
private:
    int idF;
    string nameF;
}
```

However, I can't initialize my derived class. I mean I did this Inheritance so I can add `animals` to my `PetStore` but now since `sizeF` is private how can I do that? I'm thinking maybe in the `PetStore` default constructor I can call `Farm()`... so any idea?

Comment: it's not a homework , it's just an example I made up so I can easy for you my problem !

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The constructor of `PetStore` will call a constructor of `Farm`; there's
no way you can prevent it.  If you do nothing (as you've done), it will
call the default constructor (`Farm()`); if you need to pass arguments,
you'll have to specify the base class in the initializer list:

```
PetStore::PetStore()
    : Farm( neededArgument )
    , idF( 0 )
{
}
```

(Similarly, the constructor of `PetStore` will initialize
`sizeF`, by calling the constructor of `Farm`.  The constructor of a class *always* calls the constructors of
all of its base classes and all of its members.)

Answer (score 18):

First off, a `PetStore` is not a farm.

Let's get past this though. You actually don't need access to the private members, you have everything you need in the public interface:

```
Animal_* getAnimal_(int i);
void addAnimal_(Animal_* newAnimal);
```

These are the methods you're given access to and these are the ones you should use.

> I mean I did this Inheritance so I can add animals to my PetStore but now since sizeF is private how can I do that ??

Simple, you call `addAnimal`. It's `public` and it also increments `sizeF`.

Also, note that

```
PetStore()
{
 idF=0;
};
```

is equivalent to

```
PetStore() : Farm()
{
 idF=0;
};
```

i.e. the base constructor is called, base members are initialized.

Comment: +1 "First off, a PetStore is not a farm." However I think that you don't answer the question. It looks like he need to make sure what happens on construction.

Comment: Ok now you do. However maybe use the link in my answer too? Just to be sure he understand what you mean.

Comment: thanks a lot now I got it , I just wasn't aware that PetStore() is equivalent to PetStore() : Farm() !

Answer (score 7):

The base-class constructor is already automatically called by your derived-class constructor. In C++, if the base class has a default constructor (takes no arguments, can be auto-generated by the compiler!), and the derived-class constructor does not invoke another base-class constructor in its initialisation list, the default constructor will be called. I.e. your code is equivalent to:

```
class PetStore: public Farm
{
public :
    PetStore()
    : Farm()     // <---- Call base-class constructor in initialision list
    {
     idF=0;
    };
private:
    int idF;
    string nameF;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> but I can't initialize my derived class, I mean I did this Inheritance
>   so I can add animals to my PetStore but now since sizeF is private how
>   can I do that ?? so I'm thinking maybe in the PetStore default
>   constructor I can call Farm()... so any Idea ???

Don't panic.

Farm constructor will be called in the constructor of PetStore, **automatically**.

See the base class inheritance calling rules: [What are the rules for calling the superclass constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120876/c-superclass-constructor-calling-rules)

Comment: thanks a lot , I didn't know that the superclass constructor is called automatically. but now I do thanks :)