# Constructor inheritance in templated class (C++11)

Tags: templates, inheritance, c++11, constructor, clang++

I have the following class definition:

```
template<typename T>
class Point {
  private:
    T px, py;
  public:
    Point(T x, T y): px(x), py(y) {
      std::cout << "created " << x << ":" << y <<std::endl;
    };
    T x() const { return px; };
    T y() const { return py; };
};
```

from which I am deriving specializations, e.g.

```
class PointScreen: public Point<int> {
  using Point::Point;
};
```

When I compile this in `clang++`, I get no warning / error, but the constructor is not called:

```
#include <iostream>
// definitions from above      
int main() {
  std::cout << PointScreen(100, 100).x() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This returns a random value (and also not the debug output "created..."). The value returned by e.g. `x()` is obviously "undefined".

I have just tried the same in `g++` [here](http://ideone.com/FdxXUx), and there I obtain the expected result. Is this a problem with `clang++` or have I a bug in my code?

My clang version: Ubuntu clang version 3.0-6ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_30/final) (based on LLVM 3.0). I compile with `-std=c++11 -Wall`.

Comment: Works with clang++3.4. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=3c/19f88e687067cd)

Comment: Inheriting ctors have been implemented [in clang 3.3](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html).

Comment: Is there a way to make this code work in clang 3.0?

Comment: `template < typename... Args > PointScreen(Args&&... args) : Point(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}` works as a constructor that can call all ctors of the base class (tried with with clang++3.0). Either way, you need to put make it `public` in `PointScreen`.

Comment: That template ctor doesn't take an `initializer_list` implicitly introduced via a *braced-init-list*, though (because its type isn't deduced). You'd need separate ctors for initializer-lists if using that template ctor workaround.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you need a compiler supporting inheriting constructors. From the [Apache C++11 overview](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) you can see that this feature is only available for gcc >= 4.8 and Clang >= 3.3.

For older compilers, you have to manually define all the constructors, by [calling the base constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10282787/819272). See also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/347358/819272) for more details on work-arounds.

Comment: That's what I tried and failed: Could you give an example of how I redefine the constructors?

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig Base classes can be initialized just as a regular member in the initialization-list: `PoinScreen::PointScreen(int x, int y): Point<int>(x, y) {}`

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig [Complete live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5cfc5a72cbfeb7e1)

Comment: @DyP tnx, I am on a tablet so typing an example was too cumbersome. Nice to see that the injected base class name can also be used in the initializer-list ([used to be a gcc bug](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8887864/819272))