# Invoking base class constructor in constructor of inherited class

Tags: c++, oop

I'm looking at an example of a wrapper class in this [book](https://books.google.dk/books?id=ocW3HsLs4zUC&pg=PA93&lpg=PA93&dq=AntiThetic.h&source=bl&ots=rdsEc-y5WO&sig=WPOOhwupz-h9dHAFzJT0qZPbqP4&hl=da&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjV4pK5vfzWAhWEfFAKHSMHAWoQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=AntiThetic.h&f=false). The wrapper class itself is shown at the end of this post.

On page 94 of the book there is an example of an inherited class. I have a question to what is going on in the initializer list of the constructor:

```
class RandomBase
{
public:
  RandomBase(unsigned long Dimensionality);
  virtual RandomBase *clone() const = 0;
  virtual ~RandomBase(){};

private:
  unsigned long Dimensionality;
};

class AntiThetic : public RandomBase
{

public:
  AntiThetic(const Wrapper<RandomBase> &innerGenerator) : RandomBase(*innerGenerator),
                                                          InnerGenerator(innerGenerator) {}
  virtual RandomBase *clone() const
  {
    return new AntiThetic(*this);
  }

private:
  Wrapper<RandomBase> InnerGenerator;
};
```

First of all, I can't compile this. I get the error: `error: invalid conversion from ‘const RandomBase*’ to ‘long unsigned int’ [-fpermissive]`. Secondly, I don't understand conceptually what is going on when we call `RandomBase(*innerGenerator)` - I didn't know it was possible to do this with C++ (?)

---

Here is the wrapper class Wrapper:

```
#ifndef WRAPPER_H
#define WRAPPER_H

template< class T>
class Wrapper
{
public:

    Wrapper()
    { DataPtr =0;}

    Wrapper(const T& inner)
    {
        DataPtr = inner.clone();
    }

    ~Wrapper()
    {
        if (DataPtr !=0)
            delete DataPtr;
    }

    Wrapper(const Wrapper<T>& original)
    {
        if (original.DataPtr !=0)
            DataPtr = original.DataPtr->clone();
        else
            DataPtr=0;
    }

    Wrapper& operator=(const Wrapper<T>& original)
    {
        if (this != &original)
        {
            if (DataPtr!=0)
                delete DataPtr;

            DataPtr = (original.DataPtr !=0) ? original.DataPtr->clone() : 0;
        }

        return *this;
    }


    T& operator*()
    {
        return *DataPtr; 
    }

    const T& operator*() const
    {
        return *DataPtr; 
    }

    const T* const operator->() const
    {
        return DataPtr;
    }

    T* operator->()
    {
        return DataPtr;
    }


private:
    T* DataPtr;


};
#endif
```

Wrapper taken from [here](https://github.com/cheerzzh/CPP-design-pattern-derivatives-pricing/blob/master/DesignCPP_source_code/include/wrapper.h)

Comment: The `Wrapper` dereference operator returns a *pointer*, which doesn't make much sense. Perhaps it should return a reference instead?

Comment: @ Some programmer dude: Even then, it shouldn't be convertible to unsigned long which the constructor demands.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I updated the wrapper, I found the correct implementation of it online. You are right. But even then, I'm not sure what goes on in the constructor of the derived class

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you're unsure about? What parts of the constructor of the child class are you uncertain about?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What happens in this initializer list: `RandomBase(*innerGenerator), InnerGenerator(innerGenerator)`? I am technically calling the constructor of the base class?

Comment: That's about right.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What is a good example of when this is useful? And what can it be used for? It's the first time I see this

Comment: How else would the parent class be able to initialize itself? Unlike destructors, constructor calls aren't automatically called up the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282787/calling-the-base-class-constructor-in-the-derived-class-constructor Maybe this could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error:

```
invalid conversion from ‘const RandomBase*’ to ‘long unsigned int
```

is self-explanatory, the constructor:

```
RandomBase(unsigned long Dimensionality);
```

expects an `unsigned long` yet when invoked you pass a `*innerGenerator`.

Conceptually what is going on is that your child `class AntiThetic` must invoke the base `class RandomBase` in its constructor.

So you either need to pass the correct parameter `Dimensionality` or add an empty constructor.

The wrapper seems to be a template class which allows storage and retrieval of the template parameter `T` which in this instance would be `RandomBase`.

What is confusing is why compose both a wrapper of that type and also inherit from it.

You could either inherit from `RandomBase` (as you already are), inherit from `Wrapper<RandomBase>` or compose them.