# c++ linked list to skiplist conversion

Tags: c++, linked-list, skip-lists

I want to convert a (simple linked) list into a skiplist which is derived from linked list.
Inside the conversion ctor which gets a (linked-)list as param, i get a stackoverflow at *.
I just call that ctor from main once. How is it possible that new SkipList is called loopwise?

```
class SkipList : public List {
public:     
    SkipList(SkipListEl* first) : List (first){};

    SkipList(const List& sl){                           
        ListEl* fst = sl.getFirst();
        new SkipList(fst);         // * <- stackoverflow

        while(fst->hasNext()){
            new SkipListEl(*fst);
            fst = fst->getNext();
        }
    };
```

Comment: Does SkipListEl inherit from ListEl? It seems that List has a constructor taking a ListEl* as an argument; therefore, when you call new SkipList(fst), you are calling new SkipList(List(fst)), therefore leading to an endless recursion.

Comment: Yes SkipListEl inherit from ListEl, but doesn't from List! Why can it call a ctor with argument List? I expected to call the base class ctor throught the first SkipList ctor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to review your basic C++ rules on dynamic object creation. `new` calls the constructor for the object you're creating. By calling `new object` in the constructor for `object`, you're getting an infinite loop (infinite recursion, actually) leading to no more stack space.

Comment: My intend was to call the first ctor from the second. Could you give me an advice whats wrong.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120876/c-superclass-constructor-calling-rules and it would probably be a good idea to pick up a book on C++ inheritance.