# Delegating work to the superclass' constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, polymorphism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ superclass constructor calling rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120876/c-superclass-constructor-calling-rules)

How do you delegate work to the superclass' constructor? For instance

```
class Super {
public:
    int x, y;
    Super() {x = y = 100;}
};
class Sub : public Super {
public:
    float z;
    Sub() {z = 2.5;}
};
```

How do I get `Sub::Sub()` to call `Super::Super()` so that I don't have to set `x` and `y` in both constructors?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120876/c-superclass-constructor-calling-rules?rq=1) for general super/sub class etiquette.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use constructor's member initializer lists:

```
class Super {
public:
    int x, y;
    Super() : x(100), y(100)  // initialize x and y to 100
    {
       // that was assignment, not initialization
       // x = y = 100;
    }
};
class Sub : public Super {
public:
    float z;
    Sub() : z(2.5) { }
};
```

You don't need to explicitly call base class' *default* constructor, it's automatically called before derived class' constructor is ran.

If, on the other hand, you want base class to be constructed with parameters (if such constructor exists), then you  *need* to call it:

```
class Super {
public:
    int x, y;
    explicit Super(int i) : x(i), y(i)  // initialize x and y to i
    { }
};
class Sub : public Super {
public:
    float z;
    Sub() : Super(100), z(2.5) { }
};
```

Furthermore, any constructor that *can be called* without arguments is a default constructor, too. So you can do this:

```
class Super {
public:
    int x, y;
    explicit Super(int i = 100) : x(i), y(i)
    { }
};
class Sub : public Super {
public:
    float z;
    Sub() : Super(42), z(2.5) { }
};
class AnotherSub : public {
public:
    AnotherSub() { }
    // this constructor could be even left out completely, the compiler generated
    // one will do the right thing
};
```

And only call it explicitly when you don't want base members to be initialized with default value.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Call base constructor in `member initialize list` if you want to, actually Super() constructor is automatically called.

Don't forgot to make Super destructor virtual.

```
class Super {
public:
    int x, y;
    Super() : x(100),y(100) {}
    virtual ~Super(){}
};
```

If deletion through a pointer to a Super should be allowed, then Super destructor must be public and virtual.

Comment: The Super() constructor is automatically called (no need to call it explicitly). Only make the Super class destructor virtual if this is going to be a polymorphic base type (since there are no virtual members this is not necessarily true).

Comment: Note that you **don't need to** call the base constructor, as it will be implicitly called by the compiler in this case. You only need to explicitly list *non-default* constructors (to pass the arguments). Loki is also right in that you don't always want to make the destructors polymorphic.

Comment: Please, add whitespace before `: Super()`…

Comment: Please upvote the other one, not this one, next answer captures more and better info than mine.