# Class inheritance and constructors

Tags: c++

What is the right way to do the constructors for things like this? Do I only set height and width in Rectangle?

```
class Rectangle {
public:
   Rectangle(int height, int width);
   int height, int width;
};

class Square : Rectangle {
   Square(int height, int width);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120876/c-superclass-constructor-calling-rules.

Answer (score 1):

You simply call the base class constructor at derived class's member initialization list:

```
class Square : Rectangle {
   Square(int height, int width): Rectangle(height, width)
   {
        //other stuff for Square
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do it this way:

```
Square(int sidelength) : Rectangle(sidelength, sidelength) { }
```

This way you can construct Squares with a single argument and it will invoke the Rectangle constructor with that argument as width and height.