# Derived Class Constructor Syntax Wt

Tags: c++, wt

Hello fellow C++Programmers,

today I was tinkering around with the excellent Wt framework Wt - a C++ library for
developing web applications: http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt.

Slowly but steadily I'm making progress. One thing that made me curious is
(I'm pretty new to C++) the following expression in the constructor
of a class derived from the basic Wt::WContainerWidget class:

```
class FooWidget : public Wt::WContainerWidget
{
  public:
  FooWidget(Wt::WContainerWidget *parent = 0);
  ...

  private:
  ...
};

FooWidget::FooWidget(Wt::WContainerWidget *parent = 0)
: Wt::WContainerWidget(parent)
{
  ...
};
```

Note: 
In Wt all the widgets are placed in a hierarchical tree so the optional parent argument specifies the widget that will contain our "newborn" widget.

What is happening in the ": Wt::WContainerWidget(parent)" part?
I know that the expressions behind the ":" in a constructor are used to initialize
member variables but this doesn't seem to make sense here because it's just a
class name, not the name of a member ... am I missing something important?

Many thanks in advance and regards,

Julian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the initialization list:

```
: Wt::WContainerWidget(parent)
```

it calling the base class(`Wt::WContainerWidget`) constructor with the argument `parent`. You can read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120876/c-superclass-constructor-calling-rules) for more details.