# c++ how to initialise params in derived classes

Tags: c++

```
class car
{
    string carID
    string carName
};

class electric : public car
{
    string battery
    string model
};
```

base class is `car`. `electric` is a derived class that inherits from `car`. 
What would need to be included in the constructor to initialise them and then set the values when the user inputs a new car with the data for all the attributes?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120876/c-superclass-constructor-calling-rules

Comment: @frickskit: Not sure this is the same question.. he is asking about simply initializing the fields in his derived class.

Comment: please capitalize your classes

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski Why? Class capitalization is just a question of personal style, or corporate style guides, or similar.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I do understand that it is a matter of personal style, but i believe that it makes code much more readable, and it stands out from variables and other language constructs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define constructors and subsequently use them properly. During initialization of a derived class, you should always call the appropriate constructor of the base class:

```
Derived::Derived(...):Base(...),<optional initizaliation of Derived members>{...}
```

For example:

```
class car
{
    string carID;
    string carName;
public:
    car(string carid, string carname):carID(carid),carName(carname){}
};

class electric : public car
{
    string battery;
    string model;
public:
    electric(string carid, string carname, string battery, string model)
    :car(carid,carname),battery(battery),model(model){}
};
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. How would i define the set function to set the values of a particular electric car, will i have to call the car constructor then the electric?

Comment: No, you always call the derived class constructor. As you can see in the code example I listed, the derived class's constructor calls the base class constructor during initialization.

Comment: You're welcome, if it is clear to you now, please mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

In your current model, you actually can't access any of the fields of car, because by default in C++ when using the `class` keyword, all fields are `private`.  They need to be `protected` or `public` in order for a sub-class to access them.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize base class members by calling the base class constructor at the derived class's constructor initialization list.

```
 class car
 {
    string carID
    string carName
    public:
       car (string id, string name): carID(id), carName(name) {}
 };

 class electric : public car
 {
   string battery
   string model
   public:
      electric (string id, string name, string b, string m): car(id, name), 
                                                battery(b), model(m){}
 };
```