# expected primary-expression before '*' token

Tags: c++, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I am getting the following errors in my code:

```
C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\Transfer\projects\test\My_Game\src\..\include\deathBlock.h||In constructor 'deathBlock::deathBlock(GLuint*, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float)':|
C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\Transfer\projects\test\My_Game\src\..\include\deathBlock.h|9|error: expected primary-expression before '*' token|
C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\Transfer\projects\test\My_Game\src\..\include\deathBlock.h|9|error: expected primary-expression before ',' token|
C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\Transfer\projects\test\My_Game\src\..\include\deathBlock.h|9|error: expected primary-expression before 'float'|
C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\Transfer\projects\test\My_Game\src\..\include\deathBlock.h|9|error: expected primary-expression before 'float'|
C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\Transfer\projects\test\My_Game\src\..\include\deathBlock.h|9|error: expected primary-expression before 'float'|
C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\Transfer\projects\test\My_Game\src\..\include\deathBlock.h|9|error: expected primary-expression before 'float'|
C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\Transfer\projects\test\My_Game\src\..\include\deathBlock.h|9|error: expected primary-expression before 'float'|
C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\Transfer\projects\test\My_Game\src\..\include\deathBlock.h|9|error: expected primary-expression before 'float'|
C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\Transfer\projects\test\My_Game\src\..\include\deathBlock.h|9|error: expected primary-expression before 'float'|
C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\Transfer\projects\test\My_Game\src\..\include\deathBlock.h|9|error: expected primary-expression before 'float'|
C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\Transfer\projects\test\My_Game\src\..\include\deathBlock.h|9|error: expected '{' at end of input|
C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\Transfer\projects\test\My_Game\src\deathBlock.cpp|3|error: redefinition of 'deathBlock::deathBlock(GLuint*, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float)'|
C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\Transfer\projects\test\My_Game\src\..\include\deathBlock.h|8|error: 'deathBlock::deathBlock(GLuint*, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float)' previously defined here|
||=== Build finished: 13 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

I am trying to have a subclass run a superclass constructor upon it's creation, my code is as follows:

Superclass constructor:

```
Block::Block (GLuint *Tex, float x, float y,float texx,float texy,float texw,float texh,float w,float h) {
    tex = Tex;
    Setmx (x);
    setsxw(w);
    setsyw(h);
    tx=texx;
    ty=texy;
    tw=texw+tx;
    th=texh+ty;
    Setmy (y);
    setsx (x + Getxoffset() );
    setsy (y+Getyoffset());
}
```

and superclass header:

```
#ifndef BLOCK_H
#define BLOCK_H
#include "../include/MapObject.h"
#include <GL/glfw.h>
class Block: public MapObject {
public:
    Block(GLuint *, float x, float y,float,float,float,float,float,float);
    virtual ~Block();
    void render();
    virtual void onIntersect();
protected:
private:
    float tx,ty,tw,th;
    GLuint * tex;
};

#endif // BLOCK_H
```

Subclass Constructor:

```
deathBlock::deathBlock(GLuint *Tex, float x, float y,float texx,float texy,float texw,float texh,float w,float h)
:Block(GLuint *Tex, float x, float y,float texx,float texy,float texw,float texh,float w,float h);
{
    //ctor
}
```

Subclass header:

```
#ifndef DEATHBLOCK_H
#define DEATHBLOCK_H
#include <GL/glfw.h>
#include "../include/Block.h"
class deathBlock:public Block
{
    public:
        deathBlock(GLuint *Tex, float x, float y,float texx,float texy,float texw,float texh,float w,float h);
        virtual ~deathBlock();
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // DEATHBLOCK_H
```

Additionally can someone point me towards a way to use a search engine to search for special characters? This is because all the ones I have tried don't allow this and this makes it exceedingly difficult to find relevant information.

EDIT:

This was exceedingly stupid of me, as I had just copied the parameters of the constructor straight to the initializer- causing my error.

Comment: Why do you have all those *type* declarations in your base-class construction invoke? Try: `Block(Tex, x, y, texx, texy, texw, texh, w, h)`

Comment: I am trying to do the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120876/c-superclass-constructor-calling-rules

Comment: @WhozCraig Because they're (grammatically) illegal as only *expressions* are allowed here [class.base.init]/1 and this is the error the OP is looking for. Make that an answer.

Comment: The perils of cut and paste.

Comment: @user2673108 I know what you're *trying* to do. See luke's answer again. Note how he passes derived-constructor parameters to the base class? No type decls *in the invoke* (but obviously they must be present in the base constructors *declaration*).

Comment: Also there's a semi colon you don't want.

Comment: @user2673108:  Why are you not using initializer lists instead of assignments in your constructor?

Comment: that was stupid of me, I just copied straight from the constructors parameters

Answer (score 0):

`GLunit` is defined in `#include <GL/gl.h>`.  You need to included that header before you try to use the type.

More specifically, since you are using `glfw.h`, check your defines to make sure that `gl.h` is being included (e.g. `GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE` is NOT defined) so that the `typedef` is being brought in.

Comment: http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Desktop-generic/LSB-Desktop-generic/libgl-ddefs.html  It is about the 10th line down.

Comment: [The `glfw.h` header file includes `GL/gl.h`.](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html)

Comment: @DyP:  Hence the edit to tell him to check his defines to make sure it is being included.  All of the includes in `glfw.h` are wrapped around platform defines.  If one of those isn't set, it isn't going to be included.