# no matching function for call to

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am a newbie to CPP and I am practicing inheritance. I think I got something wrong with the syntax but I couldn't tell the reason.Here is part of my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Clown{
public:
  string name ;
  void dance();
  Clown(string s) {name = s;}


};


class CircusClown: public Clown{
public:
  string name;
  void dance();
  CircusClown(string s){name = s;}
};
```

I think something wrong with my inherited class.

am using Mac so there is something wrong with displaying but here is the error:

```
Clowns.cpp: In constructor â:
Clowns.cpp:18: error: no matching function for call to â
Clowns.cpp:8: note: candidates are: Clown::Clown(std::string)
Clowns.cpp:4: note:                 Clown::Clown(const Clown&)
```

Comment: What is the question?  Are you having a problem with this?

Comment: Yes its complaining this line: CircusClown(string s){name = s;}

Comment: @Michael its a mistype I do mean C++

Comment: It's probably complaining about `name` being ambiguous.

Comment: @NobWong: ah, okay. Also, actually copy-paste the compiler error into the question, that way people can give help more easily. :-)

Comment: didn't include <string>, didn't call `Clown`s constructor either.

Comment: `Clown` needs a default constructor unless you specify which to call and you need a proper error message. And if this is a header, that using directive causes harm to anyone who uses the file, not just the file itself.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy, The derived class hides it. I'm not sure why everything is repeated, though.

Comment: Please read about `const` and references. Saves all that copy constructors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you construct the derived class, a constructor of base class must be called as well. And since your base class (`Clown`) doesn't provide the default constructor, the compiler doesn't know which one of the `Clown`'s constructors should be used.

In this case, you need to call the `Clown`'s constructor explicitly. Also avoid `using namespace std;` and consider passing `std::string` objects by `const` reference instead of passing by value:

```
class CircusClown : public Clown {
public:
    std::string name;
    CircusClown(const std::string& s) : Clown(s), name(s) { }
};
```

For more info, see [What are the rules for calling the superclass constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/120876/1168156).

Comment: but still inherited class should take input by themselves so according to what you are doing here it doesn't take any argument right when initiating?

Comment: @NobWong: `class CircusClown` from the code I posted in my answer can be used like this: `CircusClown krusty("Krusty");`.

Comment: OK I think i am just not familiar with the syntax. Thanks!