# C++ call constructor in class A from class C (inherritence)

Tags: c++, constructor, multiple-inheritance

I'm stuck with a program I'm writing after a while of fidling around and completing "c++ through game programming" book.

The situation is as follows:

```
Class A
{
 public:
  A(int x)

 protected:
  int a;

};

A::A(int x):
 a(x)
{}

Class B : public A

Class C : public B
{
 public:
  C(int x)
};

C::C(int x)
{
  A(int x);
}
```

Am I able to call the constructor of class A in the constructor of class C?

From what I think I know: B is linked to A and C is linked to B so I should be able to get to the constructor of class A from C when I am able to reach member variables and functions by derriving it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ superclass constructor calling rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120876/c-superclass-constructor-calling-rules)

Comment: Either way, this isn't real code. It won't compile. Don't forget `A::A()` is expecting a parameter.

Comment: In this case I would say you should try it and see. The compiler error messages in both clang and g++ are very informative.

Comment: I know it's not real code. Just roughly representing what I'm trying to solve.

Comment: What's wrong with writing `a=x` in the constructor body of C?

Comment: @MikeMB I altered the code after remyabel's comment. The constructor definition needed a parameter to work.

Comment: @JensAckou: Maybe I missunderstood your question. In essence: no it is not possible to call a constructor of an object after the object has been constructed (and A is constructed before the body of C's ctor is entered). But if you tell us, why you want to call the constructor of a base class, maybe we can provide you with an alternative solution.

Comment: @MikeMB Well that was some kind of confirmation I was looking for. I guess remybel's answer would be a second option even though I'm trying to keep my code as clean as I can get. I'll post a link to the source and some additional explanation in a minute.

Comment: @MikeMB http://codeviewer.org/view/code:3965 this is the code I have now in my current project. The purpose of my classes are that I can instantiate from each of them so none are actually considered abstract at the moment and every class in the chain contributes to the fact I won't need to write any methods twice for the same purpose.

Also I like to set the name of my object when creating an instance instead of calling a seperate function for setting the string.

But I think this is as clean as I will get my constructor approach unless someone has something better up their sleeves.

Comment: @Jens I still don't see, why you want to call the constructor of `Object` from within the ctor of `Player`. What information do you want to pass to `Object` that you don't want to make `Actor` aware of?

Comment: Or put differently: If you could call the ctor of `Object` how would your code look like compared to the version presented above?

Comment: @MikeMB You see in the code I posted I instantiate an object and print the name of it. My goal is when I instantiate my player object I pass the name argument between parentheses and this argument gets initialized by the object class.

By passing the the argument to actor and then to object, I'm actually done. But I thought I could pass my argument directly to my object class. Which is like it seems impossible to do because player and object are not directly related and player-actor are.

So I guess I'll stick with the solution I got now.

Comment: Ok, it's just that I see no advantage in calling the base classes's ctor directly instead of actor's. If you create an `actor` object, you'll want to initialize it with a name, too. So you have to write an appropriate ctor for `actor` anyway. I just want to say that remyabel's solution is the cleanest way to do it, even if C++ would allow calling the BC's ctor directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either try this:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    B(int x) : A(x) { }
};

class C : public B
{
public:
    C(int x) : B(x) { }
};
```

Or if you're lazy (and using [C++11](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#inheriting)):

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    using A::A(int);
};

class C : public B
{
public:
    using B::B(int);
};
```

This won't work:

```
class C : public B
{
public:
    C(int x) : A(x) { }
};

main.cpp: In constructor ‘C::C(int)’:

main.cpp:23:16: error: type ‘A’ is not a direct base of ‘C’

     C(int x) : A(x) { }

                ^

main.cpp:23:19: error: use of deleted function ‘B::B()’

     C(int x) : A(x) { }
```

Comment: So if I get this right I must make the jump in B to get in A and it's unpossible to simply call A's constructor from C because the classes are not directly related to eachother.

Comment: Because if I instantiate an object from C I know A's constructor is called automatically and it bothers me I need to write all this code in the classes in between A and C.

Comment: @Jens I know that `cplusplus.com` isn't a good source, but it seems to be almost identical to your [problem](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/48524/).

Comment: Can you give me some more information about the thread you are referring to or a link?

Comment: @Jens I can't seem to find the relevant section in the standard, so I'm going to take a (probably incorrect) guess. `B` implicitly calls `A`'s constructor, and you try to call it again in `C`, which isn't going to work. However, if `B` has nothing important, then you might has well inherit directly from `A`.