# C++ Inheritance: Calling Base Class Constructor In Header

Tags: c++, inheritance, syntax, inline, initializer-list

Assume class `Child` is a derived class of the class `Parent`. In a five file program, how would I specify in `Child.h` that I want to call the constructor of `Parent`? I don't think something like the following is legal inside the header:

```
Child(int Param, int ParamTwo) : Parent(Param);
```

In this situation, what should `Child.cpp`'s constructor syntax look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120876/c-superclass-constructor-calling-rules ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In Child.h, you would simply declare:

```
Child(int Param, int ParamTwo);
```

In Child.cpp, you would then have:

```
Child::Child(int Param, int ParamTwo) : Parent(Param) {
    //rest of constructor here
}
```

Comment: What if I don't have a .cpp file and it's something like an interface?

Answer (score 12):

The initialization list of a constructor is part of its definition. You can either define it inline in your class declaration

```
class Child : public Parent {
    // ...
    Child(int Param, int ParamTwo) : Parent(Param)
    { /* Note the body */ }
};
```

or just declare it

```
class Child : public Parent {
    // ...
    Child(int Param, int ParamTwo);
};
```

and define in the compilation unit (`Child.cpp`)

```
Child::Child(int Param, int ParamTwo) : Parent(Param) {
}
```

Comment: +1 BTW: using `implementation` instead of `definition` could be less misleading.