# Error Implementing Derived Class Constructor: "No Instance of Overloaded Function Matches the Specified Type

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

The following source aims to create an abstract base class (SubsystemClass) and a derived final class (DisplaySubsystemClass).  Implementation of the constructor for the derived class fails on error "no instance of overloaded function "DisplaySubsystemClass::DisplaySubsystemClass" matches the specified type".  I am baffled.

SubsystemClass.hpp

```
#ifndef SUBSYSTEMCLASS_HPP
#define SUBSYSTEMCLASS_HPP

#include <memory>
#include "DriverClass.hpp"

class SubsystemClass 
{
protected:
    std::shared_ptr<DriverClass> _driver;
public:
    virtual ~SubsystemClass();
    enum DriverCatalog;
};

#endif
```

DisplaySubsystemClass.hpp

```
#ifndef DISPLAYSUBSYSTEMCLASS_HPP
#define DISPLAYSUBSYSTEMCLASS_HPP

#include <memory>
#include "../SubsystemClass.hpp"
#include "DisplayDriverClass.hpp"

class DisplaySubsystemClass final : public SubsystemClass
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<DisplayDriverClass> _driver;
public:
    DisplaySubsystemClass(DisplaySubsystemClass::DriverCatalog driverCatalogItem);
    ~DisplaySubsystemClass();
    enum DriverCatalog {
        DISPLAY_DRIVER_CONSOLE,
        DISPLAY_DRIVER_CURSES,
        DISPLAY_DRIVER_SFML,
        DISPLAY_DRIVER_OPENGL
    };
};

#endif
```

DisplaySubsystemClass.cpp

```
#include <memory>

#include "DisplaySubsystemClass.hpp"
#include "SFMLDisplayDriverClass.hpp"
DisplaySubsystemClass::DisplaySubsystemClass(DisplaySubsystemClass::DriverCatalog driverCatalogItem)
{
}

DisplaySubsystemClass::~DisplaySubsystemClass()
{
}
```

Comment: You need to tell it which parent constructor to call - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120876/c-superclass-constructor-calling-rules

Comment: The compiler message is very unhelpful about this issue

Comment: I don't understand myself to be overriding the base class constructor since it does not have one; other than, perhaps, a generated default.  Am I wrong on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enumeration should be declared before its using as a parameter type in the constructor.

Comment: @DanielLee The problem is that the error message is very confusing.

Comment: Perhaps.  But I am not sure that becoming so dependent on quality error output is a good thing.  I shifted this code around for several hours and failed to notice one of the most basic mistakes; using a variable before it is defined.  That said, I am finding Visual Studio is not very helpful at all in this regard.