# two bugs in adding items to a QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to develop a project using qt but I have faced two problems both for adding items to a scene!
I have a class containing my background object and it gets a pointer to my scene in its constructor.

1. I tried "scene->addItem(this)" to add the background to the scene. however, while running the project, it is reported that the item has already been added to the scene! here is the only place I invoke addItem.
2. I am also trying to make new objects of a few classes and put them inside a QList. While adding them, the items do not appear on the scene at all!

Here is the class:

```
class Test : public QObject, public QGraphicsPixmapItem{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Test(QGraphicsScene *s){
        scene = s;
        setPixmap(QPixmap("a.jpg"));
        setPos(0, 0);
        scene->addItem(this);
    }
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event){
        list.push_back(new A(QPixmap("b.png")));
        scene->addItem(list.back());
    }
private:
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
}
```

P.S. A is class inheriting B which itself, inherits public QObject and public QGraphicsPixmapItem. The list also contains a couple of objects from type(B *).

Comment: please make it [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).. Make another project with least possible amount of code triggering your issue.. there is lot of code missing (what is myCardDeck, spc::cardNo ... ).. btw the multiple ifs looks horrible

Comment: @otopolsky Here is the edit. This is exactly what I am doing.

Comment: Do you have any code that looks something like `scene->addItem(new Test(scene))`?  Without an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as requested by @otopolsky the best anyone can do is guess.

Comment: @G.M. No I don't have any and I also haven't set any parent for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this, no time to check if it compiles etc.. take it as half answer - but still it can help you..

Your problems:

1. do not contain scene in your Test class - this is architectionally wrong,
   you can do this elsewhere in higher logic..
2. also keep the list outside of Test class.. or maybe I do not understand your intention
3. always call parents constructors in your constructor.. there are various reasons - be aware that when you have one parameter it can be inproperly converted and call the parent constructor etc.. maybe this caused problems in your constructor which had parameter of pointer to scene which maybe was passed to QObject construcor (then use explicit keyword - its much safer then) - these things are tricky.. when you have multiple inheritance I would advise always call the parent constructors manually as I did - also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/120916/3876138)
4. Why do you inherit from QObject? keep your logic out of graphics classes.. I think there is a way how to handle the mouse click event without signals (but I am lazy now to search).

--

```
class Test : public QObject, public QGraphicsPixmapItem 
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    Test(QObject *qparent = 0, QGraphicsItem *parent = 0) 
    : QObject(qparent)
    , QGraphicsPixmapItem(parent) {
        setPixmap(QPixmap("a.jpg"));
        setPos(0, 0);
    }
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) {
        emit mousePressed();
    }
signals:
    void mousePressed();
}
```

Then somewhere in your window class:

```
WindowClass(etc) : Parent(etc) { //constructor
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new ....;
    Test *test = new Test(this, 0);//can be better, lazy to think of the details
    connect(test, SIGNAL(mousePressed()), this, SLOT(on_testMousePressed());
    scene->addItem(test);
}

void on_testMousePressed() {
    list.push_back(new A(QPixmap("b.png")));
    scene->addItem(list.back());        
}
```

Comment: thanks for recommendations. I will keep them in mind. Unfortunately, none of them worked in my case:(

Comment: @Athena if you want post somewhere your whole project and I can try it out.. also you can repost if you get different errors now etc..

Comment: you can follow the project in my github account

Comment: is it [this one](https://github.com/atenagm1375/clash-royale-simulation) .. lots of files.. weird structure of directories.. but anyway, if I find some time I will have a look at it

Comment: @Athena you could at least told me which classes are the one you have problems with..

Comment: oh so sorry. It is the CardManagement but it will take time to figure out. just I would be happy if you could help me with possiblities in failure of adding an item. none of the solutions in the site worked in my case.