# what is the difference between two types of defining constructors? first one using ":" and the second one defining it in curly braces like functions

Tags: c++

I have problem in defining constructors for classes and the way I have defined them earlier, doesn't work here properly.

This is for edx c++ intermediate course. when I try to define a class that inherits from some other class, referring to my base class with a constructor doesn't work properly and so my new class won't be defined correctly. What's the difference between the first use of constructors in the first code (using ":" notation that works properly), and the second one in second code (defining like function, that I have used before properly and doesn't work here)?

I have a base class called Person and a Student class that inherits from the base class. When I try to initialize a Student object that calls one of Person class constructors, it gives wrong answers. I think this is because of the way I define constructors. I make them like functions and initialize variables in curl braces. I have used this method earlier and it was working properly, but it doesn't work here. But the standard method using ":" before curly braces works properly here. I want to know what is the difference between these two?

Person.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class Person
{
private:
    std::string name;
protected:
    int age;
public:
    Person();
    Person(const std::string & name, int age);
    void displayNameAge() const;
};
```

Person.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Person.h"
#include <iostream>

//Person::Person()
//  : name("[unknown name]"), age(0)
//{
//  std::cout << "Hello from Person::Person()" << std::endl;
//}
Person::Person()
{
    name = "[unknown name]";
    age = 0;
    std::cout << "Hello from Person::Person()" << std::endl;
}

Person::Person(const std::string & name, int age)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->age = age;
    std::cout << "Hello from Person::Person(string, int)" << std::endl;
}

//Person::Person(const std::string & name, int age)
//  : name(name), age(age)
//{
//  std::cout << "Hello from Person::Person(string, int)" << std::endl;
//}


void Person::displayNameAge() const
{
    std::cout << name << ", " << age << std::endl;
}
```

Student.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Person.h" 

class Student : public Person
{
private:
    std::string course;
public:
    Student();
    Student(const std::string & name, int age, const std::string & course);
void displayCourse() const;
};
```

Student.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Student.h"
#include <iostream>

Student::Student()
{
    course = "[unassigned course]";
    std::cout << "Hello from Student::Student()" << std::endl;
}

// first method: the right one
//Student::Student(const std::string & name, int age, const std::string & course)
//  : Person(name, age), course(course)
//{
//  std::cout << "Hello from Student::Student(string, int, string)" << std::endl;
//}
// second method: the wrong one
Student::Student(const std::string & name, int age, const std::string & course)
{
    Person(name, age);
    this->course = course;
    std::cout << "Hello from Student::Student(string, int, string)" << std::endl;
}

void Student::displayCourse() const
{
    std::cout << course << std::endl;
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Student.h"
 int main()
 {
     // Create a Student object using the no-argument constructor.
     Student Student1;
     Student1.displayNameAge();
     Student1.displayCourse();

     // Create a Student object using the parameterized constructor.
     Student Student2("Jane Smith", 25, "Physics");
     Student2.displayNameAge();
     Student2.displayCourse();

     return 0;
 }
```

expected result:

```
Hello from Person::Person()
Hello from Student::Student()
[unknown name], 0
[unassigned course]
Hello from Person::Person(string, int)
Hello from Student::Student(string, int, string)
Jane Smith, 25
Physics
```

actual result:

```
Hello from Person::Person()
Hello from Student::Student()
[unknown name], 0
[unassigned course]
Hello from Person::Person()
Hello from Person::Person(string, int)
Hello from Student::Student(string, int, string)
[unknown name], 0
Physics
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the rules for calling the superclass constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120876/what-are-the-rules-for-calling-the-superclass-constructor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Initializer List

What you are missing is the initializer list.

```
Type::Type(Parameters)
    : member1(init)       // This is the initializer list
    , member2(init)
{
    Your code
}
```

If you do not explicitly provide one then the compiler will do it for you using the default constructor for the parent class then a call to the default constructor for each member.

So lets look at your class.

```
Student::Student(const std::string & name, int age, const std::string & course)
{
     // Code
}
```

That is what you wrote. But this is what the compiler implemented.

```
Student::Student(const std::string & name, int age, const std::string & course)
    : Person()
    , course()
{
     // Code
}
```

So because you did not do anything the compiler added it calls to the `Person` default constructor and `course (std::string)` default constructor.

Now the problem comes if your base class does not have a default constructor. Then the compiler can not add the appropriate calls and will generate a compiler error.

But there is also the issue that the way you are writing this is very inefficient as you are basically initializing all the members twice. Your calling the default constructor then in the **Code** section you are re-initializing the members with another value.

```
Student::Student(const std::string & name, int age, const std::string & course)
    : Person(name, age)
    , course()                       // Initialize it to empty here.
{
    course = "[unassigned course]";  // Re-Initialize it with info.
}
```

You could simply do it once:

```
Student::Student()
    : Person()                        // Note person must have a default constructor for this to work.
    , course("[unassigned course]")
{}
```

### Temporary Object

```
Student::Student(const std::string & name, int age, const std::string & course)
{
    Person(name, age);
    // CODE.
}
```

This is not doing what you think.
Lets add the initializer list.

```
Student::Student(const std::string & name, int age, const std::string & course)
    : Person()
    , course()
{
    Person(name, age);   // This is creating a person object localy.
                         // the person object has no name so is a
                         // temporary variable and goes out of scope
                         // at the ';'. So it is created and destroyed
                         // in place before other code is executed.
                         //
                         // This does not help initialize the class.
                         // It is creating a completely different
                         // and independent object.
    // CODE.
}
```

You can see the execution here:

```
Hello from Person::Person()                       // Init parent
Hello from Person::Person(string, int)            // Init the temp object.
                                                  // If you put a print in the destructor
                                                  // You will also see that executed
                                                  // Before the Student
                                                  // This is also why the object has "unknown name" and 0 age. 

Hello from Student::Student(string, int, string)  // Now we init the student
[unknown name], 0
Physics
```

### Advice

Is there a valid scenario where you want initialized versions of the object? Personally I think not (if there are then ignore this) so get rid of the default constructors of `Person` and `Student`. Then you can not create uninitialized `Students` or `People.