# Does a super class need a default constructor?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, constructor

Consider the following:

```
# include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base{
    public:
        Base(int a) {
            cout << "Base" << endl;
        }
};

class Child: public Base{
    public:
        Child(int a) {
            cout << "Child" << endl;
        }
};

int main() {
    Child c = Child(0);
}
```

On compilation the error `no matching function for call to ‘Base::Base()’` is given. Explicitly declaring a default constructor for `Base` fixes this issue.

It seems to me that if I want to inherit from a class, then it *needs* to have a default constructor? Even though (in this example) it never gets called? Is this correct, and if so, why? Otherwise, what's wrong the above code?

Comment: `Child(int a) {` -> `Child(int a) : Base (a) {`? There **must** be a duplicate somewhere, but I am too lazy to look for it :(

Comment: Possibly duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/120876/10077

Comment: If you add a constructor that takes no arguments `Base() { cout << "Foobar" << endl; }` it'll compile and you'll find that it is actually called.

Comment: you implicitly call the default constructor `Base()`, so you need to define it. If you dont call it, you dont need it

Comment: If you don't explicitly call a particular constructor in your class initialization, then it calls the default constructor even if you don't see it in the code. Set a breakpoint to convince yourself of what I'm saying is true.  So it's incorrect to say "it never gets called."  You can give a default argument to your exisisting constructor and then it will act as a default constructor more or less.

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not a correct assumption.

You just have an error. Your derived class constructor must call the one and only Base constructor you provide which is a one parameter constructor.

```
    Child(int a)
    : Base(a)
    {
        cout << "Child" << endl;
    }
```