# How to make a derived class function always call the same base class function when called?

Tags: c++, inheritance

How do I make a base class virtual function so that it always is called when a derived class calls its version of the function? I know I can call the base classes function by writing something like `BaseClass::foo()` at the beginning of the the function `DerivedClass::foo()`, but what if I want it to be called by default, without the creator of the derived class even knowing that the base classes function does anything?

```
class BaseClass
{
     BaseClass();
     virtual void foo() {
         printf("base");
     }
}

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
    DerivedClass();
    void foo() {
        printf("derived");
    }
}

int main()
{
     DerivedClass dc;
     dc.foo();
}
```

Should print:

```
base
derived
```

Comment: Are you saying that the base function should be called *instead* of the derived function or just *before* the derived one?

Comment: Please read on how to create a [mcve]. Your question is not clear. Is the derived method also supposed to be called? Are you calling it through a pointer/reference or directly on an object? Code examples are needed.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I want it to be called before the derived function. Both the base function and the derived function should run.

Comment: This cannot be done in C++ automatically, like that. C++ simply doesn't work this way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the rules for calling the superclass constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120876/what-are-the-rules-for-calling-the-superclass-constructor)

Comment: You could have a non-virtual function in your base class, that first does something and then calls a virtual function on itself.

Comment: Why not a public non-virtual method in the base class that performs the required work and then calls a virtual private member?  That's fairly standard.

Comment: @G.M. That's a valid answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not directly possible. You could split the function in non-virtual `foo` on the base class and (pure) virtual `fooCore` on the derived classes:

```
class Base {
  protected:
    virtual void fooCore() = 0;
  public:
    void foo(){
      // do stuff, then call method of derived class
      this->fooCore();
    }
};

class Derived {
  protected:
    void fooCore() override { 
        //actual 
    };
};
```

From the "outside" the call `Base::foo()` stays the same.