# C++ does not use the desired constructor

Tags: c++

So there seems to be some problem with the solution to Problem 9-2 in the book "Object-Oriented Programming in C++, 4th edition" by Robert Lafore. So the problem is that if I would like to create a Pstring object with a statement like `Pstring = "This is a string"`, the Pstring constructor will only call the constructor with no arguments in the String class, instead of the second one with uses one char[] argument. Does anyone know what causes this kind of problem, and a fix to this? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class String                      //base class
{
protected:                     //Note: can't be private
    enum {
        SZ = 80
    };           //size of all String objects
    char str[SZ];               //holds a C-string
public:
    String()                    //constructor 0, no args
    {
        str[0] = '\0';
    }
    String(char s[])          //constructor 1, one arg
            {
        strcpy(str, s);
    }      //  convert string to String
    void display() const        //display the String
    {
        cout << str;
    }
    operator char*()            //conversion function
    {
        return str;
    }          //convert String to C-string
};
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Pstring: public String     //derived class
{
public:
    Pstring(char s[]);        //constructor
};
//--------------------------------------------------------------
Pstring::Pstring(char s[])      //constructor for Pstring
        {
    if (strlen(s) > SZ - 1)           //if too long,
            {
        for (int j = 0; j < SZ - 1; j++) {  //copy the first SZ-1
            str[j] = s[j];           //characters "by hand"
            str[j] = '\0';
        }           //add the null character
    } else
        //not too long,
        String(s);                  //so construct normally
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main() {                                        //define String
    String s1 = "This is a string"; // This works great
    s1.display();
    Pstring s2 = "This is a string"; // *** Here, nothing will be assigned to s2****
    s2.display();                    // *** Nothing will be printed here***
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `const char *` instead of `char[]`.

Comment: `String(s);` in `Pstring` constructor doesn't do what you think it does. It does **not** delegate to a base class constructor. Rather, it creates an immediately discards a temporary unnamed object of type `String`. If this is the actual code from a book, return it to the seller and demand a refund.

Comment: Your string class is not designed to serve as a baseclass. Read about the "Law of Five" ("Law of Three" for C++98) and "slicing" or "truncating".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a function parameter, a `T[]` (where `T` is `char` in your case) is really a `T*`.

In C++, a string literal is a `const char[N]` fixed array, which decays into a `const char*` pointer to the 1st element. But you don't have any constructors that accept either of those types as a parameter. A `const char*` can't be given to a `char*`. You need to add `const` to your constructors:

`String(const char s[])`

`Pstring(const char s[])`

Also, calling `String(s)` in the *body* of the `Pstring` constructor *does not* initialize the `Pstring` object using the base class `String` constructor, like you are expecting. It instead constructs a temporary `String` object that goes out of scope immediately. The `Pstring` object is not affected by that.

The only place that a base class constructor can be called by a derived constructor is in the [*member initialization list*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor). In your case, there is no such call, so the compiler *implicitly* calls the base class default (0-param) constructor before entering the *body* of the derived constructor. Which doesn't help you, since you want the base class to initialize the `str` buffer with data.

One way you can do that is add another constructor to `String` that takes a user-defined length as input, and then call that from the `Pstring` constructor, eg:

```
String(const char s[], size_t len)
{
    len = std::min(len, SZ-1);
    memcpy(str, s, len);
    str[len] = '\0';
}

Pstring::Pstring(const char s[])
    : String(s, strlen(s))
{
}
```

Note that your 1-param `String` constructor has a buffer overflow waiting to happen, since the user can directly construct a `String` object with input that is greater than `SZ` characters in length. The `String` constructor should use `strncpy()` instead of `strcpy()`:

```
String(const char s[])
{
    strncpy(str, s, SZ);
    str[SZ-1] = '\0'; // in case s is >= SZ chars
}
```

Which then makes the 1-param `Pstring` constructor redundant - especially since it is not handling the null terminator correctly to begin with, as the assignment of the terminator needs to be outside of the `for` loop, eg:

```
Pstring::Pstring(const char s[])
{
    if (strlen(s) >= SZ)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SZ - 1; j++) {
            str[j] = s[j];
        }
        // alternatively: memcpy(str, sz, SZ-1);
        str[SZ-1] = '\0'; // <-- moved here
    }
    else
        strcpy(str, s);
}
```

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote? This looks correct to me ...

Comment: @ChrisMM - I didn't downvote, but this answer was edited in the grace period. It initially contained only the bit about `const` and string literals. The OP's compiler is offering an extension, obviously, but that was completely beside the point of the question. I would assume the downvote was due to this.

Comment: How does the missing const lead to "_the Pstring constructor will only call the constructor with no arguments in the String class, instead of the second one with uses one char[] argument_"?

Comment: @juanchopanza, that's in the paragraph starting with "Also, calling `String`..." although, indirectly.

Comment: @ChrisMM I don't see the role of the missing `const`.

Comment: @juanchopanza a derived constructor *implicitly* calls a base class's default (0-param) constructor if there is no *explicit* call to a base class constructor in the derived constructor's member initialization list

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know that. But what does the missing const have to do with it?

Comment: @juanchopanza nothing at all, because a statement like `Pstring s2 = "This is a string";` will simply fail to compile altogether if a matching constructor can't be found.

Comment: That's what I thought.

Comment: @juanchopanza, but even that's had nothing to do with the failure of matching constructor, cost char* points to immutable string and char* points to mutable string, they behave differently, and using cost char* instead of cost char [] or char* instead of char [] is more efficient for many operations.

Comment: @RemyLebeau If it simply failed to compile, how would the default constructor end up being called?

Comment: @juanchopanza it wouldn't be called at all, since it wouldn't compile. But if it did compile, then the default constructor would be called *implicitly*, like I explained earlier.

Comment: @RemyLebeau But you're answering a question about observed runtime behaviour.

Comment: @juanchopanza re-read my earlier statements again more carefully

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have. Seriously, they don't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

In this conversion constructor

```
Pstring::Pstring(char s[])      //constructor for Pstring
        {
    if (strlen(s) > SZ - 1)           //if too long,
            {
        for (int j = 0; j < SZ - 1; j++) {  //copy the first SZ-1
            str[j] = s[j];           //characters "by hand"
            str[j] = '\0';
        }           //add the null character
    } else
        //not too long,
        String(s);                  //so construct normally
}
```

at first the default constructor of the class `String` is called before the control will be passed to the constructor of the class `Pstring`.

So the data member is set like

```
String()                    //constructor 0, no args
{
    str[0] = '\0';
}
```

As the argument that is the string literal `"This is a string"` that by the way as the argument has the type `const char *` due to the implicit conversion of arrays to  pointers has the length that is less than `SZ` then within the body of the constructor `Pstring` nothing is done with the data member `str`. This statement

```
String(s);
```

creates a temporary object of the type `String` that is at once deleted.

What you need is to write at least

```
strcpy( str, s );
```

instead of creating the temporary object.

Pay attention to that the constructors with parameters shall be declared like

```
String( const char s[] );
```

and

```
Pstring( const char s[]);
```

if you are going to use string literals as arguments of the constructors.

You could move this code snippet

```
if (strlen(s) > SZ - 1)           //if too long,
        {
    for (int j = 0; j < SZ - 1; j++) {  //copy the first SZ-1
        str[j] = s[j];           //characters "by hand"
        str[j] = '\0';
    }           //add the null character
} else
    //not too long,
    String(s);                  //so construct normally
```

form the constructor `Pstring` to the constructor `String` with parameter and substitute it for one call of `strncpy` like

```
strncpy( str, s, SZ - 1 );
str[SZ-1] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++, [constructors aren't allowed to be called like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/120876/10957435):

```
else
    //not too long,
    String(s);
```

C++ wants you to use its initialization list instead (see [the link above](https://stackoverflow.com/q/120876/10957435) for some examples).

If you have a portion of the construction in the parent class you would like to call from inside the child constructor, you can use a protected method instead:

```
class String                      //base class
{
protected:
    void commonTask(char s[]) {
        // do something...
    }
public:
    String(char s[])
    {
        commonTask(s);
    }
};

class Pstring: public String
{
public:
    Pstring(char s[]) {        //constructor
        if(someCondition) {
            commonTask(s);
        }
    } 
};
```

I'm using pseudo code here, but hopefully you get the idea.