# Retrieving information from a Base Class and overriding its own function returns error

Tags: c++, oop

```
class Package{

    private:
        float weight;
        float cost;
    
    public:
        Package(float weight, float cost){
            setNumber(weight, cost);
        }

        void setNumber(float weight, float cost){
            this->weight = weight;
            this->cost = cost;
        }

        float getWeight(){
            return this->weight;
        }

        float getCost(){
            return this->cost;
        }

        float calculateCost(){
            return getWeight()*getCost();
        }
};

class TwoDayPackage : private Package{

    private:
        float fee;

    public:
        TwoDayPackage(float fee){
            setFee(fee);
        } 

        void setFee(float fee){
            this->fee = fee;
        }

        float getFee(){
            return this->fee;
        }

        float calculateCost(){
            return Package::calculateCost() + getFee();
        }
};
```

Hello I have these two classes wherein `TwoDayPackage` is a derived class from `Package`. In my code flow, I would like to enter two values for weight and cost in the class `Package` and calculate its cost. However, I would also like to override the function `calculateCost()` from `Package` when I try to enter values for the additional fee in `TwoDayPackage`. Wherein, I try and get the value from the original Package and add the additional fee from TwoDayPackage.

```
int main(){

    float a, b, c, d;

    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cin >> c;

    Package pack(a,b);
    TwoDayPackage packTwoDayPackage(c);

    cout << packTwoDayPackage.calculateCost();
}
```

In main it looks like this, but I only get a wall of errors I cannot understand.

```
package.cpp: In constructor 'TwoDayPackage::TwoDayPackage(float)':
package.cpp:40:33: error: no matching function for call to 'Package::Package()'
   40 |         TwoDayPackage(float fee){
      |                                 ^
package.cpp:12:9: note: candidate: 'Package::Package(float, float)'
   12 |         Package(float weight, float cost){
      |         ^~~~~~~
package.cpp:12:9: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
package.cpp:5:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr Package::Package(const Package&)'
    5 | class Package{
      |       ^~~~~~~
package.cpp:5:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
package.cpp:5:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr Package::Package(Package&&)'
package.cpp:5:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
package.cpp: In constructor 'OvernightPackage::OvernightPackage(float)':
package.cpp:62:36: error: no matching function for call to 'Package::Package()'
   62 |         OvernightPackage(float fee){
      |                                    ^
package.cpp:12:9: note: candidate: 'Package::Package(float, float)'
   12 |         Package(float weight, float cost){
      |         ^~~~~~~
package.cpp:12:9: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
package.cpp:5:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr Package::Package(const Package&)'
    5 | class Package{
      |       ^~~~~~~
package.cpp:5:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
package.cpp:5:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr Package::Package(Package&&)'
package.cpp:5:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

It looks like this, I am not really sure where to start solving things. Please be patient with me, I just learned C++ yesterday and just got yeeted to OOP as well so I apologize in advance.

Comment: Here's a general hint. When confronted with a wall of errors, only look at the first one. Very often, fixing it will clear out a bunch of stuff, and it's a lot easier to reason about.

Comment: `TwoDayPackage` is-a `Package` and the constructor for `Package` needs a weight and a cost.  Also private inheritance and no virtual functions suggests composition should be used instead of inheritance.

Comment: `error: no matching function for call to 'Package::Package()'` Is pretty straightforward considering that the constructor of package is `Package(float weight, float cost)`

Comment: Unrelated : `class TwoDayPackage : private Package`. You sure you want private inheritance here?

Comment: @Frank but i am only allowed one  argument in `TwoDayPackage` :(

Comment: @Wander3r i was playing around the public private pizzazz but eitherway it resulted to a shitton of errors xDD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a type `Package` that can **only** be constructed if a `weight` and `cost` is provided.

```
Package(float weight, float cost){
    setNumber(weight, cost);
}
```

You also create a type `TwoDayPackage` that is-a type of `Package` and has this constructor:

```
TwoDayPackage(float fee){
    setFee(fee);
}
```

This constructor is invalid, because no weight or cost is provided to the `Package` object it derives from, producing an error, telling you that `Package` has no constructor that takes no parameters:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Package::Package()'
```

You would instead need *some way* to provide these parameters, such as:

```
TwoDayPackage(float weight, float cost, float fee)
    : Package(weight, cost)
{
    setFee(fee);
}
```

Comment: can i ask something though... TwoDayPackage(float weight, float cost, float fee)
   `: Package(weight, cost)` whats the point of this part in the program?

Comment: @arpi314 Look for the [Ask Question] button at the top of every page.

Answer (score 1):

There some "hidden" code here:

```
TwoDayPackage(float fee) { }
```

The actual code being compiled is essentially:

```
TwoDayPackage(float fee) : Package() { }
```

which tries to construct a `Package` with no parameters, so you can fix your problem by using the correct constructor instead:

```
TwoDayPackage(float fee) : Package(0, fee) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because constructor of TwoDayPackage implicitly call parent constructor, because it's need to initialize parent class with data.

You can find more [here](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120876/what-are-the-rules-for-calling-the-base-class-constructor).